# :focus isn't working but :hover works fine

Tags: html, css, tabs, hover, focus

I'm trying to make my website accessible for users that can only use the tab key. The problem I'm having is that when I try to select my floated div with the tab key, the :focus in css isn't triggered; I don't know why it isn't triggered.The hover with the mouse works fine, I find this very strange. I hope somebody can help me :)

http://jsfiddle.net/4fMex/

```
<a href="#">
<div >
<h3>lalala</h3>
<img alt="picture" src="http://boncia.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/landscape-47.jpg"/>
</div>
</a>


img{ 
width:300px;
}


div{
width:50%;
border: 3px solid black;
float:left;
}

div:hover , div:focus{
opacity:0.6;   
}
```

Comment: So it isn't possible to select a div with a tab key? I also tried a:focus but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, you can do something like this:

```
a:focus div {
 opacity:0.6;
}
```

Note that your `a` should have some `tabindex` assigned to be focusable.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4fMex/2/)

**Updated**: Looks like giving a `div` some `tabindex` also make it focusable. Although I'm not sure if this works cross-browser. So you can use your original code and just add some `tabindex` for the `div` instead of the `a`.

Comment: thank you, can't I just type div:focus if I give the div a tabindex="1" ?

Comment: @user2815780 Ah, if you mean giving the `tabindex` for the `div` instead, it's OK (I added some note in my answer).